# Python Library - Module Not Found

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I'm making a python library and i want to be able to run the code i'm developing, in another folder i have a python file, but I get the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
this is my folder structure

```
.
└── project
    └── library_directory
        ├── __init__.py
        └── main.py
    └── examples_directory
        ├── __init__.py
        └── code_directory
            ├── __init__.py
            └── test.py
```

**init**.py from library_directory

```
from library_directory.main import Class
```

test.py file

```
from library_directory import Class
```

**when I run test.py file it says: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fpdf_table'**

if i put test.py file at project level this configuration of init and test works, but i want to run the test.py in the code_directory because i will have a lot of files and don't want 15+ single files at project level

```
.
└── project
    └── library_directory
        ├── __init__.py
        └── main.py
    └── examples_directory
        ├── __init__.py
        └── code_directory
            ├── __init__.py
    └── test.py
```

i already tried absolute and relative imports but they don't work

Comment: Try change your import statement to add a dot in front of the module name e.g. from .library_directory import Class

Comment: @wgb22
it says: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
if I add the dot it searches for files in the code_directory

Comment: In your library_directory/__init__.py try adding the following line: from .main import Class

Comment: doesnt work, i think from .main import Class in init its the same as: from library_directory.main import Class

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I already tried absolute and relative imports but they don't work" This does not mean anything useful. **For each** thing that you tried, **show exactly** what was added or changed in the code, and show **what happened** as a result. Also, please try looking through the Related questions in the sidebar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure if this is the correct solution, but you can try this:
In your test module:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/Your_project_root_path'
```

Now can access to the packages in the root directory.
I took this solution from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-import-module-from-different-directory/#:%7E:text=We%20can%20use%20sys.,module%20in%20its%20current%20directory.).

Comment: This is really bad practice in production code.

Comment: That's true! It can be used for a small, unimportant project, but it is definitely not recommended. @HariharanRagothaman

Comment: it works, not the solution i was looking for, but it does the job. i can probably run this before run any "test" file. i had to use a raw string and the syntax is wrong, please edit your answer to: sys.path.insert(0, r'/Your_project_root_path')

Answer (score 0):

Your library_directory folder is a Python package. Within the package, each .py file is a module.

In your library_directory/**init**.py file, insert the line `from .main import Class`. Now you have a *package* called "library_directory", which has a *module* called "Main", and a *class* called "Class".

Now, in your environment variables, create a user variable called PYTHONPATH and add to this, the path to your project directory.

When you import in your project file, you should import using the structure: `from package.module import class`, or in your case: `from library_directory.main import Class`. The python interpreter will be able to find the package due to being in your PYTHONPATH and the **init** file directory means Python will recognise it as a package.

(You may wish to rename "library_directory" to be a bit more project specific)